# WPF binding exception with ElementName

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple window in which I wish to set the focus when opening to a `TextBox`. This I attempt to do using the `FocusManager.FocusedElement` in the XAML but I get the following error at runtime in the debug output window of Visual Studio.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=TxtBoxAttributeValue'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'NewAttributeView' (Name=''); target property is 'FocusedElement' (type 'IInputElement')

Here is the XAML code.

```
<metro:MetroWindow x:Class="Figeas.Configuration.Editor.View.NewAttributeView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Figeas.Configuration.Editor.ViewModel"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
       BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"        
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        ShowMinButton="False" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TxtBoxAttributeValue}" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"           
      Title="New Attribute">
    <metro:MetroWindow.DataContext>
        <viewModels:NewAttributeViewModel/>
    </metro:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <Border BorderThickness="10">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Content="Attribute Name:"/>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource LblValue}" Content="{Binding AttributeName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel >
                <Label Content="Attribute Value:"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxAttributeValue" Text="{Binding AttributeValue}"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <Button Content="Save" Width="100" Click="BtnSave_Click"  IsDefault="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</metro:MetroWindow>
```

I am assuming that being Embedded in a stackpanel, the `TextBox` cannot be referenced directly using its name, but I am unsure how I would go about fixing this.

Comment: Because your text box is named as `TextBoxAttributeValue`, not `TxtBoxAttributeValue`.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for pointing that out. I would have thought the designer would have flagged that. Many thanks.